# MacOS 11: NSMenu 3px too small

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, nsmenu

On MacOS 11.0 Beta (20A4299v), I created a new MacOS app project in XCode (11.4.1 (11E503a)).

I added a NSPopUpButton to the default window, and introduced the following to customize this `NSPopUpButton`:

```
@interface MyPopupButton : NSPopUpButton
@end
```

I set `MyPopupButton` as the class of the NSPopUpButton in interface designer. It is implemented as follows:

```
@implementation MyPopupButton : NSPopUpButton
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // set a long that enlarges the menu: results in width 622
    [[[self menu] itemAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"Hallo 123. Hier ein riesig langer string, der sicherlich mehr als 127 pixel breite verbrauchen sollte."];
    [[self window] setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[self menu] size].width]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification object:[self menu] queue:NULL usingBlock:^(NSNotification* nsnotification) {
        // Upon drop down, the width says 619
        [[self window] setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[self menu] size].width]];
    }];
}
@end
```

I.e. I display the `menu`s width in the title. At program start, it says 622. However, as soon as I run into menu drop down, it's suddenly 619, i.e. 3px less - without any changes from my side whatsoever.

My question: Can anybody confirm this behavior? Can anybody confirm it's a bug? Can I file an issue somewhere?

Comment: On macOS 10.13 the width changes from 663 to 625. See [size](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenu/1518185-size?language=objc) "The menu may draw at a smaller size when shown, depending on its positioning and display configuration.".

Comment: If you'd like to file an issue, there's [Feedback @ Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com) which is used for everything - OS, frameworks, developer tools, applications, ...